# Clone running machine over network

Tags: linux, debian, cloning, clonezilla

I'd like to clone a running Debian machine (ext4, no LVM) to identical hardware, preferably over the network to create a test box.

Q1) Which tools / scripts are available that allow me to do this? AFAIK *clonezilla* and *gparted* need to be started from a separate medium. Would *dd* or *ddrescue* work?

Q2) In what ways do I need to adapt the clone so that both will run in the same network segment (my home network)? The original machine has a static DHCP IP via its MAC so that won't be an issue. I thought of changing the hostname and disabling crontabs. Anything else?

Comment: Can you snapshot the original machine (e.g., are you running a filesystem that supports snapshots, or on top of LVM?)

Comment: If you can risk downtime, it's always preferrable to clone the hard drive(s) offline. Always tricky to get stuff like running databases right and to not copy lock files, sockets, block devices etc. As for actual solutions, I would recommend to search ServerFault, there are good answers to that question.

Comment: @derobert: Added info on FS type / LVM. kba: Downtime wouldn't be a problem but I'd like to automate the whole process as much as possible.

Comment: Do you need a sector-by-sector clone or would a normal (one time) copy of the first machine suffice? In the latter case I would suggest, that you

  1. boot the new machine from a live medium 
  2. partition (if need be) the hard drive and mount it
  3. set up an ssh server
  4. `rsync` the old machine to the new drive
  5. install grub on the new machine
  6. future changes are 90% done with `rsync` now. - A few things would have to be done manually, e.g. like the UUIDs in the /etc/fstab. ... But maybe I am oversimplifying.